# Debugview application not displaying properly

Tags: windows, debugview

Good day,

I'm currently experiencing a weird phenomena, this morning as I open the dbgview application an error message popped out(kernel related), couldn't remember much about the details.
Although the dbgview was showing at the task bar but as I clicked on it, it will jump out to no where.
It was as if I have 2nd monitor and it jump out to other screen.

- I checked with 2nd monitor and it was not there..

I tried to install the latest version.
System recovery back to few days before which was still in working condition. But it doesn't help.

Hope someone here could show me some clue.

07/07/2020
I discovered it might not related to debugview this app. As I opened up task bar and select the debugview application and maximize the window size it is showing up. However as long as I click restore button at the right top corner of the app it flew out to the universe again....

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DbgView remembers its last position, so what likely happened is that you disconnected a monitor while DbgView was running on it, or maybe you accidentally dragged DbgView offscreen, and now it opens in a position that's no longer visible. Try either of the following.

- With DbgView running, <kbd>Alt-TAB</kbd> to it then press <kbd>Alt-Space</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> (which opens the system menu and selects Move). While the "move" cursor is showing, use the arrow keys to bring the window back onto the active screen.
- With DbgView closed, run `regedit`, navigate to `HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\DbgView` and delete (or rename) the `Settings` value, then run DbgView again. Since it no longer finds the old saved position in the registry, it will now open in the default position on the active monitor.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I learnt something about the "last position". My first tried with external monitor(HDMI) It doesn't showed up. But I tried again with another monitor(VGA) which was the last monitor I used before I discovered the problem and it showed up !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- start dbgview
- hold the left 'Windows key'
- while still holding the windo